Functional integration of Chern-Simons action and gravitational Chern-Simons
I was studying this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05049
regarding boson/fermion dualities for Majorana fermions. In the first column of page 2 (point (ii)) they claim that integrating out the gauge field $a$ in the seed duality exactly cancels the gravitational Chern-Simons contribution. I was wondering if anyone could explain how this is achieved in practice.
